# Will Microsoft enhance SharePoint & OneDrive so that documents can be edited in application even when others are editing online?

Tags: onedrive-for-business, onedrive

I constantly have challenges with Shared Word and Excel files uploaded to SharePoint or OneDrive where it may be critical to be able to open the document up in Word or Excel client applications but also still allow other users to work on the document in online edit mode at the same time.

Having this restriction where you can't load and edit a document in the application whilst others are working on the same document in online mode is extremely frustrating, especially given the online edit mode versions of Word and Excel do not have all of the features compared to their client application equivalents.

When is Microsoft going to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

FYI. Co-authoring exists on Office Web Apps/Office Online Server.
I think it's quite difficult to lock the section you're editing with Office client as those changes will be temporarily saved locally until you save/check-in to SharePoint.